# Numpy: generate Gaussian random matrix with random.normal or random.multivariate_normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I'm trying to implement an algorithm from a paper I read that requires to generate a Gaussian random matrix. Since they don't specify anything else, I assume that it is of 0 mean and 1 standard deviation.

I found `numpy.random.normal` and `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`. Both can produce random matrices but `random.multivariate_normal` seems to be more flexible (vectors for mean and covariate matrix).

Would I get a gaussian matrix by just using `random.normal` or is that a totally different result? If it only works with `random.multivariate_normal`, what would I need to use as a covariate matrix?

Comment: I think this question is more about what that paper defines to be a Gaussian random matrix than about coding.  Without knowing what paper you are looking at, I can't hazard an accurate guess as to what their definition is.

Comment: If the paper does not provide a description of using a co-variance matrix then you are probably dealing with a 1-D Gaussian distribution in which case you use random.normal. Also, you should look at the paper's methods carefully and see what the authors said as @TravisJ pointed out.

Comment: `np.random.normal(size=(10,10))` will give a 10x10 matrix of IID standard normals.  whether this is what is needed depends on what's needed, as the above comments have also noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is Noted by "VRComp" in the comments, this is more likely the paper have used random.normal, which is much more routine in different sciences; If the authors had used "covariate matrix" in their study, they would have wrote it in the paper. Based on the problem,  Based on my experiences using various engineering numerical softwares, many of them are using "*(max_value+min_value)/2*" and "*(max_value-min_value)/2*", as default, respectively for mean value and standard deviation e.g. [Itasca_softwares](http://docs.itascacg.com/flac3d700/pfc/pfcmodule/doc/manual/ball_manual/ball_commands/cmd_ball.distribute.html). Using *random.normal* with aforementioned default values for mean value and standard deviation may result in the true answer, if 0 and 1 did not.
As I have understand from the [numpy random doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html), both modules could reach the same results using appropriate parameter specifications in one-dimensional problems. It is important to find the paper used numpy generator value, if reproducibility of the values (reproducibility) have significant effects on the results and must have the same distribution.